# How to call jquery plugin on page load

Tags: javascript, jquery, avgrund

I am trying to call a jquery (avgrund) modal window plugin on page load but I am not sure how to do it, here is what I have so far; the page for the plugin calls the plugin on button click but I wan't it to execute on page load...

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0
Strict//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html lang="en" class="no-js">
<head>
    <title></title> 
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="AvgrundModal/avgrund.css" /> 
</head>
<body>
    <div id="avtest">NO RESULTS</div>

    <!-- Include JavaScript file -->
    <script src="AvgrundModal/jquery.avgrund.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#avtest').avgrund();
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

The link to the plugin is here...
http://labs.voronianski.com/jquery.avgrund.js/

Comment: I don't have one, was wondering if there was a way to trigger the plugin on page load?

Comment: you havent included the jquery and supporting libraries in your code try adding that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change this:

```
$('#avtest').avgrund();
```

for this:

```
 $('#avtest').avgrund().trigger("click");
```

Answer (score 1):

Just trigger the `click` event after initialization.

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#avtest').avgrund().click();
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

You're missing jQuery library here:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="AvgrundModal/jquery.avgrund.js"></script>  
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
         $('#avtest').avgrund();
    });
</script>
```

and also try to change:

```
$('#avtest').avgrund();
```

to:

```
$('#avtest').avgrund().click();
```

Comment: me too think this should be the reason. but there is a <!-- Include JavaScript file --> in his code

Comment: and also he should add the jquery first right?? not avgrund.js

Comment: Yes, my mistake. Let see whether he has already included it or not :-)

Answer (score 1):

```
$(function() {
    $('#avtest').avgrund({
        height: 200,
        holderClass: 'custom',
        showClose: true,
        showCloseText: 'Close',
        enableStackAnimation: true,
        onBlurContainer: '.container',
        template: '<p>So implement your design and place content here! If you want to close modal, please hit "Esc", click somewhere on the screen or use special button.</p>' +
        '<div>' +
        '<a href="http://github.com/voronianski/jquery.avgrund.js" target="_blank" class="github">Avgrund on Github</a>' +
        '<a href="http://twitter.com/voronianski" target="_blank" class="twitter">Twitter</a>' +
        '<a href="http://dribbble.com/voronianski" target="_blank" class="dribble">Dribbble</a>' +
        '</div>'
    });
            $('#avtest').click();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

openOnEvent option worked for me.

```
$(document).avgrund({
    openOnEvent: false
});
```